# sort in explode variable

Tags: php, sorting

Hello everyone I have a small problem with the php sort I have basically a variable example

```
$ciao  ="4,v@2,f@1,x@22,a"; // Can have other elements
$prova = explode("@",$ciao);
rsort($prova);
echo $prova[0];
```

but that's out 4,v Instead I would like so 1,x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) simply.

```
<?php
$ciao  ="4,v@2,f@1,x@22,a"; // Can have other elements
$prova = explode("@",$ciao);
sort($prova);
echo $prova[0]; // Prints 1,x
?>
```

[See it working live](https://eval.in/551122)

Comment: loooooooool i try all asort rsort etc and dont try sort ...........ty man

Answer (score 1):

have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php, here you can use second parameter i.e. `sort_flags`

```
$ciao  ="4,v@2,f@1,x@22,a"; // Can have other elements
$prova = explode("@",$ciao);
sort($prova, SORT_STRING); //SORT_STRING - compare items as strings
print_r($prova);

sort($prova, SORT_NUMERIC); //SORT_NUMERIC - compare items numerically
print_r($prova);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,x
    [1] => 2,f
    [2] => 22,a
    [3] => 4,v
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1,x
    [1] => 2,f
    [2] => 4,v
    [3] => 22,a
)
```